# Ошибка выделения кода в функцию

Tags: python

Есть учебная задача. Это - пузырьковая сортировка в которой на выходе - список перестановок элементов. Так сказать - запись сортировки.
Решение выглядит так:

```
def swap_sort(array):    
    ar = list(array)
    _=''
    for ind in range(len(ar)):
        if ind>0:
            i=ind
            if ar[i]<ar[i-1]:
                ar[i-1], ar[i] = ar[i], ar[i-1]
                if  not _:
                    _ = str(i-1) + str(i)
                else:
                    _ +=', ' + str(i-1) + str(i) 

                for i in range(ind-1, 0, -1):
                    if ar[i]<ar[i-1]:
                        ar[i-1], ar[i] = ar[i], ar[i-1]
                        if  not _:
                            _ = str(i-1) + str(i)
                        else:
                            _ +=', ' + str(i-1) + str(i) 

    return _

a=(6,4,2)
print(swap_sort(a))
```

Все было хорошо, пока я не захотел выделить "подпрограмму" обмена элементов. Стало выдавать ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyCodes/WOW/swap_def/swap_bulbe_.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(swap_sort(a))
  File "F:/PyCodes/WOW/swap_def/swap_bulbe_.py", line 17, in swap_sort
    swap(ar, i)
  File "F:/PyCodes/WOW/swap_def/swap_bulbe_.py", line 8, in swap
    if  not _:
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

в таком коде:

```
def swap_sort(array):    
    ar = list(array)
    _=''

    def swap(ar, i):
        global _
        ar[i-1], ar[i] = ar[i], ar[i-1]
        if  not _:
            _ = str(i-1) + str(i)
        else:
            _ +=', ' + str(i-1) + str(i)  

    for ind in range(len(ar)):
        if ind>0:
            i=ind
            if ar[i]<ar[i-1]:
                swap(ar, i)
                for i in range(ind-1, 0, -1):
                    if ar[i]<ar[i-1]:
                        swap(ar, i)

    return _

a=(6,4,2)
print(swap_sort(a))
```

Вопрос касается только правильного выделения "подпрограммы". То есть хочется написать функцию с полезным побочным эффектом. Предложеные решения усложняют код добавлением еще одного присваивания, которого не хочется. 
Однако  поведение global стало для меня неожиданностью )))
И nonlocal тоже не помогает...

Comment: Вы пишете global _, хотя в коде не видно ее глобального объявления. А надо в данном случае через return возвращать результат функции.

Comment: С каких пор переменная, объявленная внутри функции, стала глобальной?

Comment: Кажется, вы не понимаете что такое аргументы функции, возвращаемое значение и область видимости

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нашел такое решение:

```
_=""
def swap(ar, i):
    global _
    ar[i-1], ar[i] = ar[i], ar[i-1]
    if  not _:
        _ = str(i-1) + str(i)
    else:
        _ +=',' + str(i-1) + str(i)  

def swap_sort(array):    
    global _
    ar = list(array)
    _=""
    for ind in range(len(ar)):
        if ind>0:
            i=ind
            if ar[i]<ar[i-1]:
                swap(ar, i)
                for i in range(ind, 0, -1):
                    if ar[i]<ar[i-1]:
                        swap(ar, i)
    return _


a=(6,4,2)
print(swap_sort(a))
print(swap_sort((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Результат функции `swap` - новое значение для переменной `_`. Значит нужно возвращать это значение, а не пытаться прикрутить глобальные переменные (кстати, если не умеете ими пользоваться, то лучше вообще избегать)

```
def swap(ar, i, result):
    ar[i-1], ar[i] = ar[i], ar[i-1]
    if not result:
        return str(i-1) + str(i)
    else:
        return result + ', ' + str(i-1) + str(i)
```

А вызываем так:

```
_ = swap(ar, i, _)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_=""
def swap_sort(array):    
    ar = list(array)

    def swap(ar, i):
        global _
        ar[i-1], ar[i] = ar[i], ar[i-1]
        if  not _:
            _ = str(i-1) + str(i)
        else:
            _ +=', ' + str(i-1) + str(i)  

    for ind in range(len(ar)):
        if ind>0:
            i=ind
            if ar[i]<ar[i-1]:
                swap(ar, i)
                for i in range(ind-1, 0, -1):
                    if ar[i]<ar[i-1]:
                        swap(ar, i)

    return _

a=(6,4,2)
print(swap_sort(a))
```

Глобальную переменную нужно определять до функции

Вывод

```
01, 12, 01
```

Comment: поставил решение а потом убрал. Причина: При повторном вызове этой функции все продолжает "клеиться" в переменную "_".
То есть я должен вручную очищать  "_" перед вызовом `swap_sort(array)`.
Мне надо или другое решение, или чтобы  "_" было глобальным для `swap(...)` но локальным для `swap_sort(array)`